# Setting seed boost::random

Tags: c++, boost, random, seed

I would like to reset random sequences by using different seed numbers. When running this test code:

```
boost::mt19937 gener(1);
boost::normal_distribution<> normal(0,1);
boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&,boost::normal_distribution<> > rng(gener, normal);
cout << rng() << endl;
cout << rng() << endl;
cout << rng() << endl;
gener.seed(2);
cout << rng() << endl;
cout << rng() << endl;
gener.seed(1);
cout << rng() << endl;
gener.seed(2);
cout << rng() << endl;
gener.seed(3);
cout << rng() << endl;
```

I get the following output:

```
# seed(1) via constructor
-2.971829031
1.706951063
-0.430498971
# seed(2)
-2.282022417
-0.5887503675
# seed(1)
0.2504171986
# seed(2)
-0.5887503675
# seed(3)
0.2504171986
```

Obviously I'm doing something very wrong. How may I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Following Jim, Alan and Igor suggestions made some changes to the code: `rng.engine().seed()` instead of `gener.seed()`, and called `rng.distribution().reset()` after the call to `rng.engine().seed()` and it worked like a charm.

Many thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked out!  By the way, you're allowed (and encouraged) to accept your own answer, especially if it took a combination of several people's ideas to solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

You should call normal.reset() after the call to gener.seed(). That is specified to ensure that the output of normal will not depend on any previous output from gener.

(The distribution is probably caching some state that you need to clear out.)

Comment: Yes it looks like a caching problem. I did as you suggested but I'm still getting the same results...

Comment: Normally distributed RNGs use the [Box-Muller transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) which generates random numbers in pairs (see: [Numerical Recipes examples](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/~graham/code.html))

Answer (score 2):

Great to see the problem resolved! But I guess I just figured out why Alan's method wouldn't work...

When writing `boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&,boost::normal_distribution<> > rng(gener, normal)`, you didn't create another copy of `gener` because it's a call by reference, but you *did* create another copy of `normal` with the `variate_generate`.

So instead of `normal.reset`, which only resets the original `normal`, you should use `rng.distribution().reset()`. But you can just keep `gener.seed()`, which I suspect will have the same effect as `rng.engine().seed()`.

I tested it in my code, and it worked as expected.

Well, just in case anybody would care :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe `boost::variate_generator<>` makes a copy of your `boost::mt19937 gener` object.
So when you reseed your copy of `gener`, it has no effect on the `rng` object that's already
been constructed.  Constructing a new `rng` object each time you reseed should give you the behavior you want (disclaimer: not tested!)

Comment: I believe that reseeding is having some effect on rng, because I'm getting repeated values -0.5887503675 and 0.2504171986. But then unfortunately not at all what I would expect.

Comment: Great to see the problem resolved, but may I ask why `boost::variate_generator<>` makes a copy of `gener` in this case? I think the OP passed reference when writing `boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&,boost::normal_distribution<> >`, am I missing anything?...