# C++ - Boost : Getting same random number . Seeding does not seem to work

Tags: c++, boost, random

I created a class `MyRandom`to roll a die on a uniform distribution, given the range as input:

**MyRandom.cpp**

```
#include "MyRandom.h"

MyRandom::MyRandom(){
    gen.seed(static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(0)));
}


int MyRandom::die(int min, int max){

    boost::uniform_int<> dist(min, max);
    boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::uniform_int<> > role(gen, dist);
    int result = role();
    role.engine().seed();
    role.distribution().reset();
    return result;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
std::cout <<  myRandom.die(0, 8) << std::endl; 
std::cout <<  myRandom.die(0, 8) << std::endl;
std::cout <<  myRandom.die(0, 8) << std::endl;
std::cout <<  myRandom.die(0, 8) << std::endl;
std::cout <<  myRandom.die(0, 8) << std::endl;
std::cout <<  myRandom.die(0, 8) << std::endl;
std::cout <<  myRandom.die(0, 8) << std::endl;
```

I keep getting the same number (except the first one, so my reset somewhat works). Obviously, I am not seeding this correctly. I tried to add the `reset()` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778797/setting-seed-boostrandom) without success. What am I missing?

Comment: Seed only once, not every time you're generating a random number.

Comment: It worked. I misunderstand the answer from the linked answer. It solved my problem for the consecutive calls, but not the complete problem, I need to edit my question.

Comment: Actually I figured it out. I was passing an object MyRandom myRandom = MyRandom() by value and not by reference, which causes the series of roll to be identical, because it was a copy of the generator, with the same seed :)

Answer (score 0):

The usual thing that goes wrong is something like this:

```
std::generate_n(out_iterator, 10, my_random);
```

This copies the `my_random` object complete with state. Same thing can happen with lambdas:

```
MyRandom my_random;
std::generate_n(out_iterator, 10, [=] { return my_random.die(0,8); });
```

What you want is pass the engine by referece, either doing

```
std::generate_n(out_iterator, 10, std::ref(my_random));
```

or

```
MyRandom my_random;
std::generate_n(out_iterator, 10, [&my_random] { return my_random.die(0,8); });
```

Comment: Yes, my seeding was wrong and I was passing it by value instead of reference, (that's not shown in the small sample provided - should I edit it?) and thus I was rolling identical series of rolls because i would essentially start with the same copied random dice.

Comment: You could edit it of course. That way it might be more useful to others trying to recognize their problem from your question :)